# Getting the sum value from chart

Tags: asp.net

I have a chart which describes the no.of staff in a particular department.
All that data is taken and binded to the chart using linq. 
I need to display the total no.of staff in all the departments(not the count) at the bottom of the chart.
is there any solution...???

Comment: Why can't you calculate this from the raw data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the chart control to extract SUM data. Use the Datatable (or whatever datasource you're binding your chart to) to calculate the SUM of data. Or calculate it on the DB-side.

**Update:**
to calculate sum in your datatable you can use LINQ or Compute() method:
using LINQ:

```
var sum = myTable.AsEnumerable().Sum(x=>x.Field<int>("YOUR_COLUMN_NAME"));
```

Or Compute:

```
var sum = myTable.Compute( "sum(YOUR_COLUMN_NAME)", null)
```

Comment: K. What I want to know is, We are already connecting to the data base for binding the data to the chart. Is there a necessity to connect to the DB once again?? Cant we use the data that was binded to the chart...????

Comment: You can use the data that was binded to the chart. Use Linq to be calculate sum. Something like: `var sum = table.AsEnumerable().Sum(x=>x.Field<int>("SomeProperty"));
`